# What is the best way to group a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example, I have this array:

```
$bills = array(
                 array("bill_id"=>"1", "product_id"=>"1", "total"=>"10"),
                 array("bill_id"=>"2", "product_id"=>"2", "total"=>"20"),
                 array("bill_id"=>"3", "product_id"=>"1", "total"=>"30"),
                 array("bill_id"=>"4", "product_id"=>"1", "total"=>"40"),
                 array("bill_id"=>"5", "product_id"=>"2", "total"=>"50")
            );
```

We need to add the totals of each produdct into a single array, i.e. What is the best clean fast way to generate the following array from the above one:

```
 $products = array(
                array("product_id"=>"1", "total"=>"80"),
                array("product_id"=>"2", "total"=>"70")
            );
```

Comment: Only fast way is looping. You can use some inbuilt functions if you like.

Comment: does the value of product_id ever change or remains 1 and 2?

Comment: product_id changes, about 20K products, and increasing

Comment: How is the $bills array generated? If it is returned from a database, it could be fastest to do the grouping and summing in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fastest way to sum this is index array, something like this

```
$products = array();

foreach ($bills as $bill) {
    $key = $bill['product_id'];
    if (isset($products[$key])) {
        $products[$key]['total'] += $bill['total'];
    } else {
        $products[$key] = $bill;
    }
}

var_dump($products);
```

output

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["bill_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["total"]=>
    int(80)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["bill_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["total"]=>
    int(70)
  }
}
```

to browse the invoice list

```
foreach($products as $key=>$bill) {
    var_dump($bill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thie simplest approach is a single-pass loop.

```php
$byProduct = [];

foreach($bills as $bill)
{
    $key = $bill['product_id'];
    if (!isset($byProduct[$key])) {
        $byProduct[$key] = [
            'product_id' => $key,
            'total' => 0
        ];
    }

    $byProduct[$key]['total'] += $bill['total'];
}
```

Result of `var_dump($byProduct)`:

```
array(2) {
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'product_id' =>
    string(1) "1"
    'total' =>
    int(80)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    'product_id' =>
    string(1) "2"
    'total' =>
    int(70)
  }
}
```

Another approach is to use `array_walk` but it is pretty much the same in terms of complexity:

```php
$byProduct = [];

array_walk($bills, function(&$bill) use (&$byProduct) {
    $key = $bill['product_id'];
    if (!isset($byProduct[$key])) {
        $byProduct[$key] = [
            'product_id' => $key,
            'total' => 0
        ];
    }

    $byProduct[$key]['total'] += $bill['total'];
});
```